# Emit input event on button click to change input v-model programmatically

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to make a custom `input number` with **+** and **-** spin buttons to increment or decrement the current `value` received via an `http request`, if I type numbers directly on the `input` it changes the value and when I save the content via `form POST` it works, but if I execute element.stepUp/Down the value seems to change but the received value via `POST` is the same as the original.

I was trying to `trigger` an input event with `this.$emit('input', newValue)` but it does not work because I can not specify the target to be altered. I tried to fire a custom event `this.$emit('spin-button', value)` but the input is unable to listen to the emmited event with `v-on:spin-button="myFunc()"`.

The `v-model` cannot be a `data variable` because is a dynamic form which contains more than 100 `inputs`.

I only need to dispatch an input event when I click the spin buttons after i make the stepUp/Down to alter the value, but I'm not able to achieve it.

Is there a way to emit an event to a different or sibling element?
What is the correct way to do it and change the model value? I've tried with `:value` but the result is the same.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  methods: {
    showVal(data){
      console.log(data)
    }
  },
  incrementDecrementNumber(action, event) {
   switch (action) {
    case "+": {
     event.target.parentElement.previousElementSibling.stepUp()
     break;
    }
    case "-": {
     event.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.stepDown()
     break;
    }
   }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="input-group mb-3 mx-auto col-md-6 border-dark" v-if="question.type.code === 'NI'">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <button class="btn btn-circle" @click="incrementDecrementNumber('-', $event)">-</button>
  </div>
  <input
   type="number"
   class="form-control text-center form-control-lg"
   @input="showVal($event)"
   name="`test_1_question_5"
   v-model.number="question.stored_data.answer"
  />
              
  <div class="input-group-append">
   <button class="btn btn-circle" @click="incrementDecrementNumber('+', $event)">+</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try modifying the `question.stored_data.answer` property directly. That way it'll propagate to the input element.

Comment: But I need it to increase the same step the input has.

Comment: And the number should be validated like the input number does, with min and max values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create your own component to have better control over what's going on.
That will also allow you to easily reuse it in other places.

Below is minimal example of how you can accomplish this, but can be expanded upon for better flexibility.

```js
Vue.component('spin-button', {
  template: '#spin-button',
  props: {
    'value': {
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    internalValue: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit('input', value)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    incrementDecrementNumber(action) {
      switch (action) {
        case "+":
          this.$refs['input'].stepUp()
          break;
        case "-":
          this.$refs['input'].stepDown()
          break;
      }
      /* Need to manually $emit here since the above methods doesn't trigger our computed set method. */
      this.$emit('input', this.$refs['input'].value)
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      question: {
        stored_data: {
          answer: 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="app">
  <spin-button v-model="question.stored_data.answer" step="5" min="0" max="100">
  </spin-button>
  {{ question.stored_data.answer }}
</div>

<template id="spin-button">
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button 
        class="btn" 
        @click="incrementDecrementNumber('-')"
      >
        -
      </button>
    </div>
    <input type="number" ref="input" class="form-control text-center" v-model="internalValue" v-bind="$attrs" />
    <div class="input-group-append">
      <button class="btn" @click="incrementDecrementNumber('+')">
        +
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: It seems to work in your snippet. Can you explain me please what does $attrs mean?

Comment: $attrs contains the attributes passed from the parent. In this case I'm binding it to the input. That's how the `step`, `min` and `max` props are applied to the input.

Comment: So... I dont need to set all the HTML attributes as props? Amazing. 
There is not a way to do it without a new component?

Comment: Correct, you don't need to define all the props you want to use. It it's just normal input attributes, then they should work fine with just `v-bind="$attrs"`. There might be a way to do it without, but i personally think having a component is better for reuseability.